# How I do this in switch statement

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement, nested-loops

Convert the following codes into switch statement:

```
int a = 5, b = 10, c = 15, choice;
choice = a > b && a>c ? a: (b > c ? b: c);
printf(“%d”, choice);
```

I try this way.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a = 5, b = 10, c = 15, choice;
    switch(choice)
    {
       case 'a > b && a>c':
       {
           choice=a;
           break;
       }
       case 'b > c':
       {
           choice=b;
           break;
       }
       default :
       {
           choice=c;
           break;
       }    
    }
    printf("%d",choice);    
}
```

but its output always come C. If I give a=15,b=10,c=5 output comes out 5 wheres it should be 15.  Where I did wrong??

Comment: This is not how `switch` statements work at all... You could follow some tutorials first: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/switch_statement_in_c.htm

Comment: The `case` statements must be constant values that can be resolved at compile time.

Comment: Single quotes denote a character literal, not a code sequence. In this case, it makes a lot more sense to use `if (...) {...} else if (...) {...} else {...}`.

Comment: The cases in a switch statements are equivalencies. This seems like something your professor has a very particular algorithm in mind for. You should consult your notes, a lecture recording, or ask the teaching staff directly for help.

Comment: More like `switch(a > b && a>c)`

Comment: I can't read this as anything other than `choice = max(a, max(b, c));`

Comment: You can't use nested `switch`? Granted, we're deviating from proper use of `switch` constructs.

Comment: You *can* use a switch instead of an if, `switch (condition) {case true: ... break; case false: ... break; }`, but why would you?

Comment: DO NOT nest the ternary operator. It makes your code unreadable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want largest of (`a, b, c`) to be the `choice`. `switch(logical-condition)` evaluates to either `true` or `false`.

It's not recommended to use `switch` in this scenario. However, for the learning angle:

```
#include <stdbool.h> // for true/false flags

    switch (a > b) {
    case true :
        switch (a > c) {
        case true:
            choice = a;
            break;
        case false:
            choice = c;
            //break;    //redundant
        }
        break;
    case false:
        switch (b > c) {
        case true:
            choice = b;
            break;
        case false :
            choice = c;
            //break;    //redundant
        }
        //break;    //redundant
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help . My lecturer restricted me to use <stdbool .h>.So , I use 1 for true and  0 for false in <stdio.h>.and it run properly. Thank you

Comment: @Rocky That does make me question how you're being taught. Between using `switch` in a place where it makes no sense, and not using the tools provided by the language (since C99), this seems like instructions on writing harder-to-read code.